# In Facebook instant article with WP some post content didn't display in instant Article

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-instant-articles

Here Facebook Instant article in my site is working perfectly but in one single post when i click that post in instant article it display content image, post title but the content text didn't display and in back-end of that single pots there is no any error of instant article but also content text didn't display, i have attached the that post  back-end, so can you guys help me out what's the problem and what's the solution? 
this is the post backend:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaZ9L.png
 this is the post frontend:https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0QDu.png

Comment: Could you share the code in your publishing tools with the same article?

Comment: there is instant article plugin for WordPress so i used that plugin which generates its RSS Feed and gives us URL and we used that URL.

Comment: I see. My guess is that the p tag wasn't generated. So some of them are missing. Try using "enter" instead of "shift + enter"